# GWT date picker scroll issue

Tags: css, gwt

I am using GWT datepicker in my web page .When i am adding  in the bottem of the page its 
behaviour is quite abnormal as shown in the snap shot .

I tried with z-index and with some known css properties .But i did'nt cameout from the digg.
Any other css or date picker properties will resolve this ??

[image]

Comment: IS this on a publicly accessible URL so we can see it in action?

Comment: @AlexThomas this is my locally executing projet ..do you need any other details about this??

Comment: IT defiantly smells like a `z-index` problem. Can you stick it all into [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: I did'nt deal with any css properties.i just added date picker control at the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I got the solution for this

```
dateIcon.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
        {
            int left = dateIcon.getAbsoluteLeft() + 30;
            int top = dateIcon.getAbsoluteTop() + 10;
            if(dateIcon.getAbsoluteTop()+400>Window.getClientHeight()){
                top = dateIcon.getAbsoluteTop()-200; 
            }
            popUp.setPopupPosition(left, top);
            if (isControlEnabled()) 
        ![enter image description here][2]  {
                popUp.show();
            } else 
            {
                popUp.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```